# How can I change the build-in toolchains in eclipse cdt mingw32

Tags: c++, mingw, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I am compiling on windows with cdt/mingw. I like to compile warning free. I get the following warning:

```
auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified
on the command line.
```

The following page suggests the way to deal with it is to just adding that option to the command line of ld.

[4.8 ld and WIN32 (cygwin/mingw)](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/WIN32.html)

The question is thus, how do you change the default command line switches for the built in toolchains?

I would also like to set the warning level of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the parameter to the linker via gcc's [`-Wl` parameter](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> `-Wl`,*option*
>
> Pass *option* as an option to the linker. If *option* contains commas,
>   it is split into multiple options at
>   the commas. You can use this syntax to
>   pass an argument to the option. For
>   example, `-Wl,-Map,output.map` passes
>   `-Map output.map` to the linker. When
>   using the GNU linker, you can also get
>   the same effect with
>   `-Wl,-Map=output.map`.

So, you need (and me too :)) `-Wl,--enable-auto-import`.

For controlling warning levels, see the [official docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: actually passing options directly to the linker is completely fine, and anyway this does not answer the question: The question is thus, how do you change the default command line switches for the built in toolchains? See my own answer for a partial solution on project basis.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I maintain my own Makefile (as opposed to letting Eclipse generate one) so I kinda skipped the part where you should add `-Wl,-Map,output.map` to, for example, the variable `CXXFLAGS` - GNU make uses that one in it's implicit rule for linking (you can see the full list via `make -p`).

Answer (score 1):

Hi so far I have found a partial solution to this problem. I have not found how I can change the **default** toolchain options, but I have found how to change them on a project basis.

In *project->properties->C++-build->settings*

It seems to make more sense if it would be in *tool chain editor*, but it isn't.

There you have a tab called *Tool Settings* and looking down there is *MinGW C++ Linker->Miscellaneous*.

Here on the right you can add extra linker options. Above you also have the compiler and warning settings are implemented as checkboxes which is nice.

So far at least I have gotten started, only a pity I have to do that over for every project individually.

Oh for further confusion, this is not always there, and I have some old projects from before I installed MinGW and who thus have no real toolchain installed. In that case the settings pane only has the *Binary Parsers* and *Error Parsers* tabs, so it looks completely different. The secret is in having the *Tool Settings* Tab. Very dynamic and for the rainforest like settings dialog of eclipse also very confusing.

[image]